# If $a, b, c$ are Real numbers such that, $a < b < c$, prove $|a-b| + |b-c| = |a-c|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm taking an advanced calculus class and we have to do this for homework and I'm not sure where to start. The $a < b < c$ confuses me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what the symbol | | means?

Comment: Notice that $\vert a - b \vert + \vert b - c \vert = (b - a) + (c - b) = c - a = \vert a - c \vert$.

Comment: “$a<b<c$” means that $a<b$ and also $b<c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a<b<c$, then $|a-b|+|b-c|=(b-a)+(c-b)=c-a=|a-c|$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

- $a<b\iff b-a>0$
- if $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$ and if $x>0$ then $|x|=x$

Answer (score 1):

If $a<b$, then $\vert a-b\vert=b-a$.

For example, $\vert3-5\vert=\vert-2\vert=2=5-3$.

Can you use this to solve your problem? Note that you have $a<b$ and $b<c$.